# Attributing credit for programming languages used

Tags: licensing

I'm working on a website and was hit with the thought of "do I need to give credit for the languages I'm using to build my website with?" I wasn't able to find any sort of licenses for HTML, CSS, or JavaScript and I'm a bit confused on the wording of PHP's license.

My question is: Do I need to specify somewhere on my website (externally or internally) that I'm using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, and MySQL (and attribute credit, linking to their licenses if they have one, etc)?

Comment: The end user visiting the webpage will be unaware of any php or mysql you've used.

Comment: You do not need to credit toolmakers for the works you create using their tools. An analogy would be giving credit to Shakespeare for your English novel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IANAL ... etcetera.

This is not a licensing concern.  Most of the technologies you listed have no licensing implications whatsoever.  The others (PHP and MySQL) have open source licenses that don't require any acknowledgement to be displayed.

The answer is No.

---

> I wasn't able to find any sort of licenses for HTML, CSS, or JavaScript ...

These are all open standards, and the copyright statements for open standards don't place any constraints on what you can do with implementations.  They only relate to the text of the standard itself.  (If you want to find them, the best place to look is in the specifications themselves.)

> ... and I'm a bit confused on the wording of PHP's license.

We can only help you with that it if you say what you find confusing.  (It looks pretty straightforward to me.)

Comment: The [PHP License](http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt) has several clauses that I'm confused on whether they refer to the use and distribution of applications that use the _language_ PHP or if they're referring to the underlying source code that makes up PHP. Specifically I'm looking at point 6.

Comment: @RobertHolman First, your code doesn't have any PHP *engine* code, it just uses the PHP language. Second, if you're only using PHP to power your Web site, you're not redistributing your server-side code anyway.

Comment: @RobertHolman - apsillers has nailed it re clause 6.  Using PHP in a website is not redistributing.  Redistributing is when you include the PHP >>code<< in something you make available to other people.

Comment: @aspillers - Ah. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 1):

IANAL and all that, if you want legal advice consult a lawyer.

That said, there are three areas of law here that are of interest: Copyright, Patents, and Trademarks.

The easy one first: **trademarks**. Trademark law has the goal of preventing misrepresentation: when you sell something, the buyer associates your brand with certain qualities (or lack thereof); selling the thing under a competitor's brand will harm the customer (because they don't get what they think they're getting), and also the competitor (because you can leverage the brand image of your competitor's quality products to sell cheaper rip-offs). Trademark law is not about forcing people to credit anyone or anything, but rather about keeping them from "crediting" wrongly. For example, if Foobar were a trademarked programming language, it would probably be illegal for you to market one of your C++ programs as "built with Foobar"; and even if you *had* built it with Foobar, you'd still have to be cautious in whether or not you could advertise this fact.

Then, **copyright**. While the documentation and specifications of a programming languages are copyrightable, as well as the source code of a reference implementation, the language itself is not, and programming in it does not constitute a derived work. If Foobar were a programming language, and its specifications, official documentation, and reference compiler were published under extremely restrictive licenses, then you would still be free to publish your own Foobar code, and you would retain full copyright over it. And because no copyright would apply, you would be under no obligation to credit or not credit whatsoever.

Compiled binaries are trickier, because compilers usually link hard-coded snippets into your binaries, and those snippets, being part of the compiler itself, *are* copyrightable, which makes your binary a derived work. Whether or not you can freely distribute your binaries, then, depends on two things: are the snippets introduced by the compiler significant enough to be considered copyrightable (this is a gray area, really), and if so, what does the compiler's license say about them. In most cases, though, the compiler author explicitly allows shipping your binaries, and draws well-defined lines around those parts of the development tools / SDKs that you are allowed to redistribute (often, this part is referred to as a 'redistributable').

Libraries, of course, are a different beast: a library is typically included in a binary distribution, and as such, it becomes part of it, and the binary distribution becomes a derived work of the library, which means the library's original license governs the conditions under which you may distribute your binary. This is also the case for standard libraries that come with typical programming languages.

Running code on a server is yet another situation. Just putting your code or binaries on a web server and running it there does not constitute publishing, and as long as your code's output does not serve any significant (as in, significant enough to be copyrightable) parts of the toolchain itself, again the language implementation's copyright does not apply. Serving image files with apache, for example, does not make the HTTP responses I serve derived works of apache itself. Serving apache's own source code with apache however does. Also note that, similar to the library issue in binary distributions, responses generated by a server often contain significant portions of server-side libraries; for example, an ASP.NET application might serve widgets that render using hard-coded template code, and if that template code is significant, copyright might apply. (To my knowledge, however, the .NET license agreements explicitly disclaim copyright over such responses.)

And then there's **patents**. The official stance is that patents are designed to support innovation by rewarding someone who has developed a useful solution or procedure *and* is willing to invest money in developing it to the market by giving them exclusive rights to using this idea for a limited amount of time. In practice, however, it leads to a situation where 'vultures' go and patent everything they can get their hands on, and then sue people for applying obvious solutions to common problems. This is not a problem you'll solve with crediting though; whether you credit or not, whether it's based on your own original work and research or not, it doesn't matter at all in the face of patents: all that matters is whether someone holds a patent on whatever technique you're using, and whether they are willing to sue you over it.

So, most likely, you won't have to credit at all. Especially with open source tools, however, it is considered a nice gesture to credit the (free) tools you used anyway: it doesn't cost you much, and it helps make the tools better in the long run (free advertising == more users == more testers and more contributors == more bugs found & fixed and more features implemented == better software). So even if the license doesn't mandate crediting, or the situation is such that copyright does not apply (which is generally what you're looking at), you might still *want* to give credit. Not because you have to, but because it's a nice helpful thing to do.